# Running Java on Sublime Text 2

Tags: java, compilation, sublimetext2

I have allready compiled my `*.java` files in Sublime Text 2 and even can run them. But the problem is, my source files are in the path `src/` and the class files in `bin/` when i build a calss without package specified i cun run them because there are in the folder `bin/` but when i have a specifiend package it try to find the class in `bin/` and not in `bin/org/packagename/`.

The build-system file have the next:

```
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "cmd":
            [
                "javac",
                "-classpath",
                "D:/POO/TF_V2_7/bin",
                "-d",
                "D:/POO/TF_V2_7/bin",
                "$file"
            ],
            "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
            "name": "MyJavaC",
            "selector": "source.java",
            "shell": true,
            "variants": [
                 { "cmd": 
                 [
                    "java",
                    "-classpath",
                    "D:/POO/TF_V2_7/bin",
                    "$file_base_name"
                 ],
                   "name": "Run"
                 }              
             ]
        }
    ]
```